# nth child click in javascript to open new web page

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, css-selectors, tr

I need a code that would open new page on first table element click.

So far I managed to get this work:

```
<script>
var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('xl9624916')[1]; 
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
    location.href = url;
}); 
</script>
```

But it is not the best solution for me because this page being published from excel and element names changes on every republish event.
Hence needed specific table child on click.

Please help me to understand what is it wrong with the code below?

```
<script>
var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
var element = document.querySelectorAll("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)");
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
location.href = url;
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` will give you list of all the elements matching the selector. So, you cant add listener directly on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insted of using the querySelectorAll use querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector


var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
var element = document.querySelector("table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)");
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: @RemigijusDzingelevicius Thanks for accepting the answer